# Rails 4 - File upload as per user subscriptions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ccavenue

I have a Rails app, where users can upload pictures and videos.Now i want the uploads to be controlled as per the plans/subscriptions selected by the users, as i am integrating it with [CCAvenue payment gateway](https://github.com/kevivmatrix/active_merchant_ccavenue/blob/master/README.rdoc) as i want to process the transactions in INR, which currently *stripe* do not support and with *Paypal*, its a hell of integration. So i decided with CCAvenue.

Every user has many pictures and many videos and upload is done with famous [jquery.fileupload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), where every upload file can be checked for size and number of files before upload, which i have already done. I want these values to be controlled as per the plan.

For example, if user chooses Gold plan, he can upload 20 pictures and 10 videos and also reply back on rating and customer comments.

**in image_upload.js**

```
//how can i pass dynamic value, other than catching it from hidden field.
            //10mb
            maxFileSize: 1000000,
            maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
```

Moreover, these values will be used again on other views to limit and toggle anchor links to reply to comment,customer etc.

i think, creating a **global App object** **during initialization** will help and this will contain all required values throughout the app.Something like this:

```
window.App = {
"plan_id" ; 1,
"plan_type" : "Gold",
 .....
.....


}
```

And injecting this global object after the user registers using a helper tag in my `application.html.erb` ..something like shown below-

```
<%if user_signed_in/%>
   <%= inject_global_object(current_user.id)%>
<%end%>
```

And this will be defined in my application_helper, so i need some help for that too.

which approach is better for a lifelong solution?

1. hidden field (which is just a quick fix, but not ideal)
2. global window object, provided by a helper in my layout file
3. is there something better than the above two?

Comment: Can't you do something like `maxNumberOfFiles: <%= @package.max_images - @current_record.images.count %>`. It will caluclate while page loading and allows to upload only the max files that user can do.

Comment: what about other details like videos, replies and more activities that user will have?